# How to handle printed curly braces in early evaluation of String.Format in a custom WriteLine in C#

Tags: c#, string.format

I'm writing a C# code generator in C#. However, I'm running into a problem printing initializer lists. I've dumbed down my code generator to a contrived example. Suppose I'd like to output the following class:

```
class Foo
{
  private static int[] m_bar = new[] {256};
}
```

Here's an example program to do that:

```
class Program
{
  private static int m_indentLevel;

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var arrayDimension = 256;

    WriteLine("class Foo");
    WriteLine("{{");
    m_indentLevel++;

    // This works because the format string is passed all the way through to the 
    // Console.WriteLine
    string initializer = String.Format("new[] {{{0}}}", arrayDimension);
    WriteLine("private static int[] m_bar = {0};", initializer);

    // This doesn't work because the format string is evaluated before the Console.WriteLine.
    var intirim = String.Format("private static int[] m_bar = {0};", initializer);
    WriteLine(intirim);

    m_indentLevel--;
    WriteLine("}}");
  }

  private static void WriteLine(String format, params Object[] arg)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", new String(' ', m_indentLevel * 2), String.Format(format, arg));
  }
}
```

This program keeps track of indentation in the output and uses a custom `WriteLine` method to indent the given string to the proper level. My problem comes when the user of my custom `WriteLine` uses curly braces (escaped) in the given format string *and* calls my `WriteLine` without specifying the optional  `arg`, i.e. they evaluate the format string before passing it to me.

Notice that the first attempt to write `private static int[] m_bar = new {256};` succeeds while the second throws an exception.

Is it possible to make my `WriteLine` work in both situations? How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe write an overload of your `WriteLine`: `public static void WriteLine(string s) { ... }` which handles that case appropriately? `String.Format()` has a lot of overloads, for similar reasons. The whole design bugs me though. It seemed "quick and easy" to do everything with `String.Format()`, and now you're in quicksand. I know the feeling very well. It's not going to get any better from here. IMO the first time you run into a weird ambiguity tangle like this, take it as a dire warning. Cut your losses and redesign.

Comment: @Ed - Both the overload you suggest and the conditional Mike suggested work just fine. Is one preferred (faster?) over the other?

Comment: Overloads are resolved at compile time so mine would be sub-microscopically faster. The performance difference is to small to care about. I prefer mine because you've got two different semantics for the `format` argument. Hence, it should be two distinct methods that happen to have the same name. That's just my view -- it's your call. That said, [here's a helpful illustration of me evaluating the implications of your design](http://wheresthejump.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Invasion-of-the-Body-Snatchers-1.jpg).

Comment: @Ed. Yeah. My use of all the `String.Format` calls may not be the best, but I appreciate you answering my question as posed anyway. Care to add the overloads as an answer?

Comment: FWIW, I agree that @Ed's suggestion is better. I've been doing too much JavaScript (also why I lowercased `Length`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `WriteLine()` to have two different semantics for the `format` parameter depending on whether or not there are any additional parameters following it, my own preference would be to write an overload for that case:

```
/// <summary>
/// Indent s and write to Console.Out without String.Format() interpolation
/// </summary>
public static void WriteLine(string s) { ... }
```

This follows `Console.WriteLine()` and `String.Format()` practice; both have quite a number of overloads. That's necessary in part because overload resolution with `params` and `object` is tricky, fragile stuff. Be constantly on the alert out for the wrong overload getting called.

That said, [your design scares me](http://wheresthejump.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Invasion-of-the-Body-Snatchers-1.jpg). It reminds me of "quick and easy" designs I've come up with over the years, where I thought I could use some language feature to do most of the work for me, and I rapidly found myself thrashing around in quicksand. You get a bunch of cool stuff that you want for free -- but you get a lot of other stuff besides that doesn't suit your needs at all well.

It's like you're using an octopus to lash a canoe to your car. Certainly, it has all those nice long grippy tentacles, but it has its own agenda. In the long run, rope may turn out to require less effort and ingenuity on your part, when all is said and done.

Answer (score 1):

`intirim` will contain `"private static int[] m_bar = new {256}"`. You're passing that to `String.Format`, which will look for `arg[256]`. Since you're not passing any params, it obviously fails. I'd probably add a conditional to `WriteLine` like:

```
string formatted = arg.Length > 0 ? String.Format(format, arg) : format;
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", new String(' ', m_indentLevel * 2), formatted);
```

But as Ed says, be careful, the rabbit hole is dark and deep...

Comment: Thanks. `arg.length` should be `arg.Length`. I can't fix it because of the minimum character limit on edits.